# Eigenvectors of perturbed circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory, fast-fourier-transform, circulant-matrices

I have a circulant matrix defined by a positive kernel W(x):

$W_{ij} = W(|i-j|)$

where W is defined on positive reals (so we are sampling {1,2,...,N} to create the matrix). I know this has eigenvectors which are the Fourier basis and constructed using the Nth roots of unity.

Now, if W(x) depends on a parameter r that varies very slowly with the row of the matrix:

W = W(r,x)

so that the new matrix is now defined by:

$W_{ij} = W(r(i),|i-j|) $

How do I find the new eigenvectors of this matrix?

Numerically I see that they are localized.